# Access violation OpenCV C++ dll

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, opencv, access-violation

I'm new to c++, 
I get the access violation exception whenever I try to construct an object
the constructor is as follows

```
Image::Image( IplImage* pIplImage, bool bDestroy )
    : m_bOwned( bDestroy )
{
    memcpy( static_cast< IplImage* >( this ), pIplImage, sizeof( IplImage ) );

    if ( bDestroy ) 
        cvReleaseImageHeader( &pIplImage );

}
```

and the destructor is

```
Image::~Image()
{
    if ( m_bOwned )
        cvFree( reinterpret_cast< void** >( &imageDataOrigin ) );
}
```

EDIT 1: Class definition

```
class VISION_EXPORT Image
    : public IplImage
    , private boost::noncopyable
{
public:

explicit Image( IplImage* pIplImage, bool bDestroy = true );
~Image();
private:    
bool m_bOwned;
};
```

It was working before, but now when I export it as dll.. it doesn't work any more.
Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you need own C++ wrappers for the OpenCV image structures when the library already provides a C++ interface?

Comment: its a part of a middleware and I should use it as it is.

Comment: where do you get an access violation?  IT could just be that you'd written past the end of an array and written through the heap which can cause subsequent allocations to throw access violations.

Comment: Equally we need to see how Image is defined so that we can be sure that the memcpy you are doing is ok.  The static_cast of this looks very strange ...

Comment: I double checked on it and the memcpy isn't the line that is causing the error, and by the way the image wrapper is derived from IplImage

Comment: the error is caused by the destructor

Comment: You'd better check your CRT settings.  Anything other than "share the same CRT between modules" is a kaboom.  You didn't disclose your compiler make and model so nothing to nail down beyond that.

Comment: You stomp on the object instance and then wonder why you get an AV?

Comment: could you please give me more details about the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Note that IplImage is a struct, not a class.  Therefore you can't inherit from it - i.e., "class Image : public IplImage" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Er, ok, upon thinking about it, you can technically have a class inherit from a struct in c++, but I'm guessing that that is almost surely not what you intended to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a `memcpy()` that writes to the memory pointed by the `this` pointer. When you do that you trash the internal structure of the object. Instead, what you should do is add a member variable to your `Image` class. For example:

```
class Image {
protected:
    pIplImage* m_pImage;
    bool m_bOwned;
// ... whatever else you need here ...
};
```

Then your implementation could be something like this:

```
Image::Image( IplImage* pIplImage, bool bDestroy )
: m_pImage(pIplImage), m_bOwned( bDestroy )
{
}

Image::~Image()
{
    if ( m_bOwned )
        cvReleaseImage(m_pImage);
}
```

As you see above, I don't think you need to copy any data. The code that instantiates this class decides if it wants to pass ownership of the image to the class or not, but either way the `Image` class just copies the pointer.

**Edit**: after looking at your code I think I have an idea of what could be wrong. The IplImage pointer passed to the constructor was allocated by the main application and deleted by the DLL. I bet the problem is caused by the two different allocators acting on the same block of memory. You should make sure that memory is allocated and deallocated by the same allocation functions. You may even have OpenCV linked against your main app and also against your DLL, and these are two separate instances of the same library.

**Edit #2**: See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx) for a deeper explanation of the problem. As I said in the comments, if you want to avoid this problem you will need to reorganize your code to avoid cross-module memory allocation/deallocation.

Comment: Thanks very much .. but the problem is that I'm not allowed to change in the wrapper, because it is used in many other classes. And I tried to track the source of the error and it seems to be the destructor. Can you help me out to resolve this?

Comment: As I said, what you are doing is not guaranteed to work, the layout of a C++ class is not the same as a structure in most cases, so you can't copy data into the memory pointed by the this pointer. Post more of your code, in particular you should show how the Image class is defined.

Comment: This will happen even if I'm creating the object in my application?

Comment: Well, yes. If you create a IplImage in your main app, then its image buffer is allocated by the app's memory allocator. The allocator used by the DLL does not know about it, it can't delete it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, pardon me but I'm new to c++ .. is there a work around to avoid this problem?

Comment: Could you please be more precise, I'm a java programmer and dealing with memory allocation and dlls is new to me. What exactly can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: I added a link at the bottom of my answer. It links to a very good article regarding this problem. I hope it helps.